# EJB timer not execute job

Tags: timer, scheduled-tasks, wildfly, ejb-3.0

The execution is not launching any scheduled job.
Is it something left?

Environment:

- Java 8
- Javaee 7
- Wildfly 10

**Job**

```
@Singleton
public class TimerJob {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Schedule(hour = "23", minute = "59", persistent = true, info = "Hello programades")
    public void execute() {
        logger.info("Timer Job execution " + new Date());

    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", persistent = false, info = "Prova de programació")
    public void executeTest() {
        logger.info("Actuacio Job execution TEST" + new Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that you're using [@javax.ejb.Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) rather than [@javax.inject.Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html);
2. Add [@javax.ejb.Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) to your class declaration otherwise then bean will not exist until you reference it from somewhere else.